# Zend Route Regex Reverse problem with forward slashes

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes, reverse

I have a problem with reverse for regex routes, my config file is below:

```
routes.route1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.route1.route = "([^\,]+)([^p]*)(?:\,page_[0-9]+)?\.html"
routes.route1.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.route1.defaults.action = "find"
routes.route1.map.1 = "url_path"
routes.route1.map.2 = "url"
routes.route1.map.3 = "options"
routes.route1.map.4 = "page"
routes.route1.reverse = "%s%s,page_%d.html"
```

the url will be http://www.site.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/cat5/title-id1_id2,page_1.html
the number of categories is unspecified
current regex works fine, and gets all the categories at once, but the reverse formats all forward slashes to html format: %2F
does anyone know how I can keep the forward slashes? I need the reverse for pagination and all the html entities look just plain ugly.

thx :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the URL helper, set the fourth parameter to false to disable the encoding (which is on by default). So something like:

```
<?=$this->url(array(
   'url_path' => 'whatever',
   'url' => 'something'
   'options' => 'foo',
   'page' => 'bar'
), 'route1', false, false)?>
```